# Convertendo inteiro para string em C#

Tags: c#

Como converto um número inteiro para uma string? Já tentei pesquisar em lugares e não achei a resposta, estou com esse problema apenas para finalizar meu projeto, se alguém conseguir colaborar, agradeceria!

Comment: Tenha em atenção o tipo de questões que coloca, preguntas demasiados genericas correm o risco de ser fechadas. Recomendo a leitura da normas do forum em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 7):

Utilize o método de extensão `ToString()`:

```
int numero = 10;
string numeroString = numero.ToString();
```

Uma observação, caso sua variável inteira aceite valores nulos e seja nula, ao utilizar o método `ToString()` irá ocorrer  o erro `NullReferenceException`. Para evitar esse problema utilize o método `Convert.ToString()`, caso o valor informado seja `null` ele irá retornar string vazia.

```
int? numero = null;

// O retorno será ""
string numeroString = Convert.ToString(numero);

// Será lançada a exceção NullReferenceException
string numeroStringComErro = numero.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta utilizar o *Convert.ToString;*

```
var x = 2;

var result = Convert.ToString(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá

Existem várias formas de tratar a conversão e tipos no .NET, a implicita e explicita, neste caso a explicita é a recomendada.

```
int numero = 10:
string explicitString1 = numero.ToString();
// ou
string explicitString2 = Convert.ToString(numero);
```

Já agora a implicita será algo deste tipo

```
int valor1 = 10;

object valor2 = valor1;

// converter implicitamente 
int valor3 = (int)valor2;
```

Comment: Você chama os dois exemplos de "explícitos"